# can i create s sub-list without using li or ul tags

Tags: html

I am trying to create an e-commerce store using drop-down menus for easy navigation, but can not seem to create a super-sub menu within my nav bar for the e-liquids tab, how can i do this without using the **li** or **ul** tag lines?

I have tried the current code shown, however the new drop-down content in the store for e-liquids is now constantly visible.

I have also tried implementing the **li** tag but it does not stick to the navbar.

```
.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
}

.navbar a {
    float: left;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.dropbtn {
    font-size: 20px;
    border: none;
    font-family: calligram;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: grey;
font-size: 20px;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    min-width: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: lightblue;
    padding: 12px 16px:
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
<div class="navbar">
    <a href="vapeshop.html">Home</a>
    <a href="about us.html">About us</a>
    <a href="contact us.html">Contact us</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Store</a>
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="mods">mods</a>
            <a href="tanks/rda">tanks/rda's</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">e-liquids</a>
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="high VG">High VG</a>
                <a href="medium VG">Med VG</a>
                <a href="Low VG">Low VG</a>
            </div>
        </div>
            <a href="accesories">accesories</a>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

i was hoping that it would create a sub-sub menu, however it does not

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be visible because it looks like no CSS rules are applied that will make it non-visible. An easy way to achieve this (if you aren't using any CSS libaries) is to write your own class which has the `display: none;` property, and to use JS to show and hide the element when necessary.

Attach this class to the element so it is always hidden as a first step.

What you will also need is `mouseover` event listener attached to your drop-down containing the sub-menu. You'll also need to add a new class or ID to your drop-down containing the sub-menu so that it can have an event attached to that element only. Also add an ID to your sub-menu so it can be easily referenced in JS.

For example:

```
<div class="dropdown" id="subMenuParent">
  <button class="dropbtn">e-liquids</a>
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content hidden" id="subMenu">
    <a href="high VG">High VG</a>
    <a href="medium VG">Med VG</a>
    <a href="Low VG">Low VG</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Because you have attached the CSS class `hidden` to the sub-menu, we now are going to 'toggle' this class on the CHILD element using mouse-over via JS.

```
<script>
 var subMenuParent = document.getElementById('subMenuParent');
 var subMenuChild = document.getElementById('subMenu');
 subMenuParent.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  subMenuChild.classList.toggle('hidden') 
 });
</script>
```

This is a start to get you on the right track, but basically want you want to think about is how the element is going to appear when hovered over.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, I have got the css, i just forgot to upload it with the comment, however would this solution still work, and is there a way of doing it only using html or would i have to use java?

Comment: Same principles apply. You'll need to use JavaScript to add the event listener. You can inject the content between the <script></script> tag in your HTML, just before the </body> closing tag.